# how to access mosquitto logs on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi2, mosquitto, debian-jessie

I am using Jesse on my RPi and i have installed mosquitto (along with mosquitto client of course)..I am doing a project which requires me to write a js script that will access the logs of the mosquitto broker and client. I know how to do the javascript part but i have no idea where the mosquitto log files are stored.Can anyone help me?

Comment: If it is started by `systemctl` at boot-time, I would try looking in the `systemctl` boot script for mosquitto.

Comment: ok i searched around in systemct1 but i didnt find it....but i did find the logs in /var/log.In that I found a folder called mosquitto which held a file called mosquitto.log